# Object Splicing within Array not giving correct result

Tags: javascript, lodash, splice

In my application i want to splice objects from an array upon matching, I am using lodash function for splicing like as shown below, unfortunately the json is not splicing correctly,

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kxopenbg/)**

Can anyone give me some suggestion for this issue

```
var arr = [{
    name: 'Jack',
    id: 125
}, {
    name: 'Jack',
    id: 125
}];

var result = _.without(arr, _.findWhere(arr, {name: 'Jack'}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

**Expected result**

```
[]
```

**Actual Result**

```
[{"name":"Jack","id":125}]
```

**Update 1**

Even using normal JavaScript way also giving the same output

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];

    if(obj.name === 'Jack') {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#1
var arr = [{
    name: 'Jack',
    id: 125
}, {
    name: 'Jack',
    id: 125
}];

var result = _.rest(arr, function (el) {
  return el.name === 'Jack';
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // "[]"

#2
var arr = [{
    name: 'Jack',
    id: 125
}, {
    name: 'Jack',
    id: 125
}, {
  name: 'foo',
  id: 124
}];

var result = _.rest(arr, function (e) {
  return e.name === 'Jack';
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // "[{\"name\":\"foo\",\"id\":124}]"

// 3 also you can use _.filter if you do not want slice of array... 

var result = _.filter(arr, function (e) {
  return e.name !== 'Jack';
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // "[{\"name\":\"foo\",\"id\":124}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

_.findWhere returns only the first matching element. So that you can use _.difference and _.filter or _.rest to do the task

```
_.difference(arr, _.filter(arr,function(d){ return d.name = 'Jack' }));
```

You can implement the same using pure javascript using the code below.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    if(obj.name === 'Jack') {
        arr.splice(i, 1); 
        i--; // Splicing of elements will cause shifting of indices in the array
    }
}
```